# Efficient way to replace values in a column starting from a list of pairs

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, duplicates, tuples

I'm trying to replace duplicates in my data, and I'm looking for an efficient way to do that.

I have a df with 2 columns, idA and idB, like this:

```
idA   idB
22    5
22    590
5     6000
```

This is a df with similarities.
I want to create a dictionary in which the key is the id, and the value is a list with all the devices linked to the key. Example:

```
d[5] = [22, 6000]
d[22] = [5, 590]
```

What I'm doing is the following:

```
ids = set(gigi_confirmed['idA'].unique()).union(set(gigi_confirmed['idB'].unique()))

dup_list = list(zip(A_confirmed, B_confirmed))

dict_dup = dict()


for j in ids:
    
    l1 = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(dup_list)):
    
        if j in dup_list[i]:
            
            l2 = list(dup_list[i])
            l2.remove(j)
                       
            l1.append(l2[0])
            
            dict_dup[j] = l1
```

Is it possible to make it more efficiently?

Comment: It's really not clear what your code is doing... First question, what is `tqdm` and where is it defined? Second, if you just want a dictionary where the key is the id from either idA or idB and the value is the list of ids from the other for any line where that id appears (that's my guess from your example), it would be a lot more efficient to build it directly into a dict mapping keys to sets of keys.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I noticed I forgot 2 lines on top! My bad... I added them.
1) tqdm is  a library for creating a 'time bar'.
2) Yes, you got it!
3) can you expand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to do some guessing here, because you question is no super clear, but the way I understand it, you want a dictionary that maps each id in `idA` or `idB` to the list of ids found on the other side, from that id.

If I understood your problem correctly, I would solve it by directly constructing a dictionary mapping ids to sets of ids.

```
idA = [22, 22, 5]
idB = [5, 590, 6000]

dict_dup = dict()
for a, b in zip(idA, idB):
    if a not in dict_dup:
        dict_dup[a] = set()
    dict_dup[a].add(b)

    if b not in dict_dup:
        dict_dup[b] = set()
    dict_dup[b].add(a)
```

After this runs, `print(dict_dup)` outputs

```
{22: {5, 590}, 5: {6000, 22}, 590: {22}, 6000: {5}}
```

which I think is the data structure you're looking for.

By using dicts and sets, this code is very efficient. It will run in linear time over the number of ids.

##### Shorter code with defaultdict

You can also make this code a lot shorter by using a `defaultdict` instead of a regular `dict`, which will automatically create those empty sets when needed:

```
from collections import defaultdict

idA = [22, 22, 5]
idB = [5, 590, 6000]

dict_dup = defaultdict(set)
for a, b in zip(idA, idB):
    dict_dup[a].add(b)
    dict_dup[b].add(a)
```

The print statements produces slightly different output, but it's equivalent:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {22: {5, 590}, 5: {6000, 22}, 590: {22}, 6000: {5}})
```

This still contains the info you want, and is just as efficient as the first solution.

##### Putting it back in your data frame

Now, if you need to put this information back in your dataframe, you can use dict_dup to efficiently retrieve what you're looking for for each row.

Comment: THANKS!!!! You missed many info but you nail it! I feel as if I learned a lot from your code. I'll definitely remember for a lot of time!

Comment: Glad I could help!