# Faster way to iterate over columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following task.

I have this data:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
data = {'name':  ['Todd', 'Chris', 'Jackie', 'Ben', 'Richard', 'Susan', 'Joe', 'Rick'],
    'phone': [912341.0, np.nan , 912343.0, np.nan, 912345.0, 912345.0, 912347.0, np.nan],
    ' email': ['todd@gmail.com', 'chris@gmail.com', np.nan, 'ben@gmail.com', np.nan ,np.nan , 'joe@gmail.com', 'rick@gmail.com'],
    'most_visited_airport': ['Heathrow', 'Beijing', 'Heathrow', np.nan, 'Tokyo', 'Beijing', 'Tokyo', 'Heathrow'],
    'most_visited_place': ['Turkey', 'Spain',np.nan , 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Spain',np.nan , 'Spain']
    }
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

What I have to do is for every feature column (most_visited_airport etc.) and its values (Heathrow, Beijing, Tokyo) I have to generate personal information and output it to a file.

E.g. If we look at most_visited_airport and Heathrow
I need to output three files containing the names, emails and phones of the people who visited the airport the most.

[image]

[image]

Currently, I have this code to do the operation for both columns and all the values:

```
columns_to_iterate = [ x for x in df.columns if 'most' in x]
for each in df[columns_to_iterate]:
    values = df[each].dropna().unique()
    for i in values:
        df1 = df.loc[df[each]==i,'name']
        df2 = df.loc[df[each]==i,' email']
        df3 = df.loc[df[each]==i,'phone']
        df1.to_csv(f'{each}_{i}_{df1.name}.csv')
        df2.to_csv(f'{each}_{i}_{df2.name}.csv')
        df3.to_csv(f'{each}_{i}_{df3.name}.csv')
```

Is it possible to do this in a more elegant and maybe faster way? Currently I have small dataset but not sure if this code will perform well with big data. My particular concern are the nested loops.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The fact that you're searching the whole dataframe multiple times for each i in values will certainly make this code quite slow. This approach is appropriate for searching for a small number of items in a data frame, but since you're planning to be exhaustive, I would turn the loop around. Loop once only through your data, and add values to dictionaries of sets. E.g. a dict where keys are airports, and values are sets of names. The results will take linear time in your data size.

Comment: @joanis so you suggest changing the for i in values loop?

Comment: @Krblaze I meant something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70763394/3216427 but adapted to your data. But Mad Physicist's solution is very nice, I doubt my idea would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the call to `unique` with a `groupby`, which would not only get the unique values, but split up the dataframe for you:

```
for column in df.filter(regex='^most'):
    for key, group in df.groupby(column):
        for attr in ('name', 'phone', 'email'):
            group['name'].dropna().to_csv(f'{column}_{key}_{attr}.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
cols = df.filter(regex='most').columns.values
def func_current_cols_to_csv(most_col):
    place = [i for i in df[most_col].dropna().unique().tolist()]
    csv_cols = ['name', 'phone', ' email']
    result = [df[df[most_col] == i][j].dropna().to_csv(f'{most_col}_{i}_{j}.csv', index=False) for i in place for j in
              csv_cols]
    return result


[func_current_cols_to_csv(i) for i in cols]
```

also in the options when writing to csv, you can leave the index, but do not forget to reset it before writing.